# Apache Jelly XML template: conditionally render tag attribute

Tags: java, xml, jelly

I am using a [Jelly script](http://commons.apache.org/jelly/overview.html) to generate an HTML ordered list. Sometimes I want `<li value="...${computed}...">...big block...</li>` and other times I want just `<li>...</li>` with no `value` attribute. `value=""` is not legal - it must be an integer.

I could use `<j:choose>` to write two blocks, one using `value` and one not, but then my template has to duplicate all the content inside the list item, which would make it uglier and harder to maintain.

In XSLT, you can use `xsl:attribute` for this purpose. Is there any equivalent in Jelly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that making `${computed}` evaluate to either a list of digits or `null` is enough. While `<li value="">blank</li>` produces invalid HTML (same as the source template), `<li value="${null}">null</li>` produces `<li>null</li>` which is what is wanted.

Comment: Implemented as: https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/commit/63b829a482431cdd4e4592ca78799412f4dead5a